# vscode.executeDefinitionProvider returns empty vscode.Location[] when tests are called via package manager

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-business-central

I'm creating my first VS Code extension, but now I stuck while testing my extension automatically.
If I run my automated tests out of VS Code everything works fine, but I want to run the tests also in a continuous integration pipeline which is why the tests should also run if I call them with `npm run test`.

With `npm run test` most of my tests run successful, but as far as a test-method depends on the "vscode.executeDefinitionProvider"-output the tests fail, because it does not find any definitions.

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand<vscode.Location[]>('vscode.executeDefinitionProvider', document.uri, positionToSearchForSymbols)
  .then(definitions => {
    if(definitions.length > 0){
      //this one is called if I run the tests out of Visual Studio Code
    } else{
      //this one is called if I run the tests via npm rum test
    }
  });
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why does `npm run test` behave different than running the tests out of VS Code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

David

Comment: Generally: 1) A `DefinitionProvider` (`vscode.executeDefinitionProvider`) can come from a 3rd party. Depending on that third party your tests fails or succeeds. (as you figured in your answer). Important to note is: Your tests containing this third party extension (DefinitionProvider) might not be reproducible on other machines, that are setup with a different DefinitionProvider. Maybe think of create your own mocked/stubbed DefinitionProvider exclusively for your tests in order to make them reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got informed that VS Code sends a message to the language provider (in my case the al language extension) and that the issue has to be on the site of the language provider. Because the issue is not related to VS Code, I will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to setup your test environment to use specific extensions:
   [How do I run integration tests for a vscode extension that depends on other extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546059/how-do-i-run-integration-tests-for-a-vscode-extension-that-depends-on-other-exte/69384906#69384906)
- You need to make sure that the extensions (in your case: `DefinitionProvider`) are activated before your tests start: 
  [VSCode extension testing: Use `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` in test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357424/vscode-extension-testing-use-vscode-executedefinitionprovider-in-test)
- You might run into a situation where nothing of the above works for you. In that case this might help: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400358/6702598