# VSCode extension testing: Use `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` in test

Tags: visual-studio-code, automated-tests, vscode-extensions

#### Background

I'm trying to auto-test my VSCode extension. The extension works with python files and uses `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` and `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider` on them.

#### Problem

`vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` always returns  `[]`, `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider` always returns `undefined`.

#### Notes

When running the same code in a debug session of the extension (no test session), the commands work flawless.

I ensured the extensions to be available during the test and even manually activated them with

```
let ext = vscode.extensions.getExtension("ms-python.python");
assert.notStrictEqual (ext, undefined);
await ext?.activate ();
ext = vscode.extensions.getExtension("ms-python.vscode-pylance");
assert.notStrictEqual (ext, undefined);
await ext?.activate ();
```

#### Question

How do I get the commands to succeed during automated test.

#### Edit: Workaround

Apparently VSCode takes its time to **really activate** the extensions. I could get it working placing a `await sleep (10000);` in `index.ts`::`run ()` before `return new Promise((c, e) => {`.

While this is working, it's a really unstable workaround, Is there any way to make the code wait until the whole environment is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Extension<T>::activate(): Thenable<T>`
>
> Returns: `Thenable<T>` - A promise that will resolve when this extension has been activated.

```
await ext?.activate();
```

Comment: Didn't work.....

Comment: @DarkTrick Then the extension does some async stuff until it is operational

Comment: Tried it again, worked this time. Maybe my placement at first was bad? It's working now, being places right after `suite('Python tests', async () => {`.

Comment: VSCode seems to be very random here. After another day, the code suddenly stopped working. Perhaps it only worked due to some buggy incremental build of npm.

Answer (score 1):

In the end nothing really stably worked for me, so I resorted to the following (perfectly fine working) solution.

**My auto tests are run from the productive environment, like any other extension.**

- In `package.json` I created a new command _test.
- the command would run `./test/suite/index.ts : run()`.